# Localstorage persistent textarea does not work

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, textarea

I'm trying to make the content in a textarea persistent i.e. stay when the page reloads. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <textarea id="txt" onchange="store()"></textarea>
      <div id="err"></div>
      <script>
         function store() {
         if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
          var textarea = document.getElementById("txt")
             localStorage.setItem("text", txt.value);
             document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("text");
         } else {
             document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = "Localstorage not supported";
         }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: revise your code

Comment: What are you trying to do here? You get the value of  the `<textarea />` element, then reset the same element to the value you just got?

Comment: Your code only runs when the value inside the textarea changes. When the page reloads, it technically doesn't change (it's just empty). You need to run this code when the page starts up too.

Comment: @lux I'm trying to make the text the user typed in stay when the page reloads using Localstorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is only called when the `textarea` changes, you also need to call it when the page loads. To do this you should listen for the [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
  <textarea id="txt"></textarea>
  <div id="err"></div>
  <script>
  var textarea = document.getElementById("txt");
  textarea.addEventListener('input', writeLocalStorage);

  function writeLocalStorage() {
     if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
         localStorage.setItem("text", textarea.value);
     } else {
         document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = "Localstorage not supported";
     }
  }

  function readLocalStorage() {
     if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
         textarea.value = localStorage.getItem("text");
     } else {
         document.getElementById("err").innerHTML = "Localstorage not supported";
     }
  }

  // `DOMContentLoaded` may fire before your script has a chance to run, so check before adding a listener
  if (document.readyState === "loading") {
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", readLocalStorage);
  } else {  // `DOMContentLoaded` already fired
      readLocalStorage();
  }
  </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried running your code on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FWJUIEOOAE8A) and it doesn't work.

Comment: I also tried it as a .html file on chrome and it doesn't work.

Comment: @FourCinnamon0 well there were some other issues with your function, you continually read and overwrite the localStorage in the same pass. I edited my answer to make reading and writing from localStorage into separate functions. Also note that the `change()` event is not reliable for textarea and I changed it to `input()`.